# Debounce function call, and clear trailing ones

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using React and trying to debounce function call from my text input value change.

I have a text input where on every `inputValue` change `useEffect` is fired and data is being fetched from API with the value that was input:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect');
    fetchDataFromAPI();
  }, [inputValue]);
```

I want `fetchDataFromAPI` to be debounced and all trailing debounce calls to be cleared.

What I tried so far is:

```
const debounce = (func, wait, immediate) => {
  let timeout;

  return function executedFunction() {
    var context = this;
    var args = arguments;

    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };

    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    console.log('clearTimeout');
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);

    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};


const AsyncComponent = ({
  value,
}) => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  const fetchOptions = async () => console.log('fetchOptions');
  const debouncedFetch = debounce(() => fetchOptions(), 1000);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect');
    debouncedFetch();
  }, [inputValue]);

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      value={value}
    />
  );
};
```

[Source](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-use-the-debounce-function-in-javascript)

However what this code does is that **it does not cancel the trailing function calls**.
The API call is debounced 1000ms, but the quantity of API calls are the same as inputValue changes.

**Result on four letters typed**:

[image: Console log flow]

Answer (score 1):

You're currently declaring a *new* instance of the `debouncedFetch` function every time the component renders, and each of these function instances have a different binding for the `timeout` variable.

Either declare the debounced function outside the component:

```
const debounce = (func, wait) => {
  let timeout;
  return () => {
    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      func();
    };
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
  };
};
const fetchDataFromAPI = () => console.log('fetchOptions');
const debouncedFetch = debounce(() => fetchDataFromAPI(), 1000);
const MyApp = () => {
  useEffect(debouncedFetch, [inputValue]);
  // etc
}
```

Or move out the `timeout` variable so that every render's call to `debouncedFetch` has a consistent reference to a single `timeout` binding:

```
let timeout;
const debounce = (func, wait) => {
  return () => {
    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      func();
    };
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
  };
};
const fetchDataFromAPI = () => console.log('fetchOptions');

const MyApp = () => {
  const debouncedFetch = debounce(() => fetchDataFromAPI(), 1000);
  useEffect(debouncedFetch, [inputValue]);
  // etc
}
```

If you need to pass arguments, rather than use `arguments` and `.apply(context, args)`, it would be easier to read I think if you managed that in the *callback* you passed, eg:

```
useEffect(() => debouncedFetch('arg1', 'arg2'), [inputValue]);
```

Comment: Fantastic answer!